# With htaccess remove .php extension from any file name, add trailing slash with query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove .php extension from given any file name with htaccess and add trailing slash with query string. It should work in localhost also.

```
Case 1: 

http://localhost/demo/order/?oid=123&stat=open (in the browser)
to 
http://localhost/demo/order.php?oid=123&stat=open (internal)

Case 2: 

http://mydomain.com/order/?oid=123&stat=open (in the browser)
to
http://mydomain.com/order.php?oid=123&stat=open (internal)

It should work for any file name like order.php, contact.php, member.php, ...
```

I tried this, it is working but I want to add trailing slash at the end of the file name with query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I tried many, but not exactly reached to my requirement.
Like remove .php extension, add trailing slash, add query string. But not all these in one .htaccess file. I want all these in one .htaccess file as specified in the above requirement.

Plz help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /custom/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /custom/(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working for me. URL in the browser http://localhost/demo/order/?oid=123&stat=open and it should internally work like http://localhost/demo/order.php?oid=123&stat=open

Comment: That is exactly it is doing. If you enter URL as: `http://localhost/demo/order.php?oid=123&stat=open` it gets redirected to `http://localhost/demo/order/?oid=123&stat=open` and that is internally rewritten to `/demo/order.php?oid=123&stat=open` (if /demo/order.php file exists)

Comment: I tried this in localhost http://localhost/custom/hello/?hello=world, It says object not found (404). hello.php file is there in the custom folder.

Comment: If this .htaccess is placed in `DocumentRoot` then it should load `/custom.hello.php` file. Try this rule in **EDIT** and also provide me error line from error.log when you get 404

Comment: I have placed the htaccess file in the "custom" folder not on the root. I have updated the htaccess file with the edit you have given. Still not working. URL is rewriting as I expected like http://localhost/custom/hello/?hello=world, but giving 404 object not found error.

Comment: Can you please change the below code to what I am expecting `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%1 [NC,L,QSA]` This is working but I need to append trailing slash at the end of the file name with query string

Comment: Oh you didn't tell before that you are lacing this in `custom` folder. I have edited as per that. Try this in `custom/.htaccess`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have one more requirement on the same task. I want to remove trailing slash at the end of the file name only if there is no query string. `eg: http://localhost/custom/member/ to http://localhost/customer/member`. If query string is there then it should be like `http://localhost/custom/member/?id=2375`

Comment: I request opening a new question as that seems a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$  /$1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you please change the below code to what I am expecting `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%1 [NC,L,QSA]` This is working but I need to append trailing slash at the end of the file name with query string